# Length validation in field triggers error icon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, user-experience

I'm trying to make an icon, tooltip or chatbubble appear in a field when a user tries to input a longer string than the field should accept. I've googled this extensively and I'm rather astounded that this seems to have no easy solution. I've found simple solutions to change the field appearance when the input is invalid but none that flash a warning and retain a legal previous value in the field.  How would one go about achieving this?

Comment: That's a great idea, especially that part: "retain a legal previous value in the field". What specific problem you are stumble with (hint: there is no question mark in the question)?

Comment: So, like an [`ErrorTemplate`](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/690130/simple-validation-in-wpf)?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to this is with an `ErrorTemplate` and `ValidationRule`s.

First you'll need a ValidationRule, in your case something that checks the length of a string.

```
public class StringLengthRule : ValidationRule
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (((string)value).Length > MaxLength)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Input too long!");
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

you can attach that to the binding of your view, e.g.:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" <!-- or LostFocus -->
                 Path="Text">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:StringLengthRule MaxLength="15"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Depending on your Style/Template this will look something like this:
(I've included the Style and Template at the bottom of this answer)

[image: Error Template]

This will work for internal errors too. If you bind to an int for example:

[image: Example 2]

You can use the same Validations to check if all inputs are valid before closing a dialog.

```
public static class ValidationHelper
{
    public static bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        // The dependency object is valid if it has no errors and all
        // of its children (that are dependency objects) are error-free.
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) &&
        LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj)
        .OfType<DependencyObject>()
        .All(IsValid);
    }

    public static bool ShowValidHint(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        if (IsValid(dependencyObject)) return true;

        MessageBox.Show(Strings.WarningInput, Strings.InputError, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Focus();
    if (ValidationHelper.ShowValidHint(this))
        DialogResult = true;
    else
        // show error
}
```

As for the *retain a legal previous value* part. This is best done via the `PropertyChangedCallback` or `CoerceValueCallback` of your `PropertyMetadata` or (if you are using `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead) the property setter. I personally would recommend against it. If you change the value back, the value would be valid again and people who type looking at their keyboard might not even know what they did wrong.

---

Can't remember where I have this template from, but I've been using it for cases like this for ages.

## Control Template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!-- Defines TextBox outline border and the ToolTipCorner -->
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1.25" BorderBrush="#FFDC000C">
            <Grid>
                <Polygon x:Name="toolTipCorner" Grid.ZIndex="2" Margin="-1" Points="9,9 9,0 0,0" Fill="#FFDC000C" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
                <Polyline Grid.ZIndex="3" Points="10,10 0,0" Margin="-1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" StrokeThickness="1.5" 
                              StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <!-- Defines the Popup -->
        <Popup x:Name="placard" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=toolTipCorner}" PlacementRectangle="10,-1,0,0">
            <!-- Used to reposition Popup when dialog moves or resizes -->
            <Popup.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!-- Shows Popup when TextBox has focus -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.IsFocused}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <!-- Shows Popup when mouse hovers over ToolTipCorner -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=toolTipCorner, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <!-- Hides Popup when window is no longer active -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=IsActive}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Popup.Style>
            <Border x:Name="errorBorder"
            Background="#FFDC000C"
            Margin="0,0,8,8"
            Opacity="1"
            CornerRadius="4"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"
            MinHeight="24"
            MaxWidth="267">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4"
                          Color="Black"
                          Opacity="0.6"
                          Direction="315"
                          BlurRadius="4"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"
                 Foreground="White"
                 Margin="8,3,8,3"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

## The Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm constantly amazed at the verbosity of solutions to simple problems in WPF.  Is it just me?  I can think of how to solve this in Java with just several lines of code (ten tops).  MVVM and WPF is a page of code.

Comment: It will take me some time to investigate if this solves the problem.  I will update after some work.  Thank you.

Comment: @ÁrniSt.Sigurðsson So ... did it help?

Comment: Not before I went on vacation.  Will look into it again tomorrow.  I've since been presented with a significantly "simpler" solution.  I will tend this question when I have a fuller understanding of the components.